# Splunk create Pie chart from JSON map

Tags: pie-chart, splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard, splunk-formula

my application logs everyday a json containing a map for a Pie chart.

For example this JSON:

```
{
  "telemetryEventName": "active-deliveries",
  "telemetryData": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "repo-01",
      "gitTextsInformation": [
        {
          "key": "es-ES",
          "value": "47"
        },
        {
          "key": "pt-BR",
          "value": "46"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "repo-02",
      "gitTextsInformation": [
        {
          "key": "es-ES",
          "value": "12"
        },
        {
          "key": "pt-BR",
          "value": "13"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

It cames from a log message, and I'd like to create a Pie chart for each `gitTextsInformation`

I already tried to create a table:

```
"index"="main" "kubernetes.container_name"="..." logger_name=telemetryLogger message.telemetryEventName="..."
| head 1 
| table message.telemetryData{}.gitTextsInformation{}.key message.telemetryData{}.gitTextsInformation{}.value
```

But it is not working as a search for creating the Pie chart

Answer (score 1):

The problem is there is only one event, which makes for an uninteresting pie chart.  Yes, there are multiple data points in that event, but Splunk cannot plot multi-value fields.  The workaround is to put each data point into its own event.

The `mvexpand` command will break a multi-value field into multiple events, but it only works with one field.  Using `mvexpand` on one field and then another breaks the association between the fields.  To maintain the relationship between keys and values, we first have to combine them into a single field, run `mvexpand`, then separate the keys and values.

````
index=main "kubernetes.container_name"="..." logger_name=telemetryLogger message.telemetryEventName="..."
| head 1 
``` Combine the keys and values to retain their relationships ```
| eval data=mvzip('telemetryData{}.gitTextsInformation{}.key', 'telemetryData{}.gitTextsInformation{}.value')
``` Put each key/value pair into their own event ```
| mvexpand data
``` Put keys and values into their own fields ```
| eval data=split(data,",")
| eval key=mvindex(data,0), value=mvindex(data,1)
| table key value
````

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you can use spath to process

```
| makeresults 
| eval data ="{\"telemetryEventName\":\"active-deliveries\",\"telemetryData\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"repo-01\",\"gitTextsInformation\":[{\"key\":\"es-ES\",\"value\":\"47\"},{\"key\":\"pt-BR\",\"value\":\"46\"}]},{\"id\":\"2\",\"name\":\"repo-02\",\"gitTextsInformation\":[{\"key\":\"es-ES\",\"value\":\"12\"},{\"key\":\"pt-BR\",\"value\":\"13\"}]}]}" 
| spath input=data path="telemetryData{}" output=telemetryData 
| mvexpand telemetryData 
| table telemetryData 
| spath input=telemetryData path="name" output=name 
| spath input=telemetryData path="gitTextsInformation{}" output=gitTextsInformation 
| table name, gitTextsInformation 
| mvexpand gitTextsInformation 
| spath input=gitTextsInformation 
| stats values(value) by key, name
```

If you need separate pie charts for each repo name, you can use trellis as below

[image]